# wrong static library archive name on release scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, linker-errors

I have some static libraries with different product name for Debug and Release scheme. For example, I have TestLib library with product name:

- **Debug: TestLib_d**
- **Release: TestLib**

Project targets and static library targets all have the Debug and Release config.

It runs well and all static library archived with the correct name (ex: **libTestLib_d.a** for Debug and **libTestLib.a** for Release).

But when I build the project with **Release** scheme, the linker fails:

```
...
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/[PROJECT_TRUNK]/libs/TestLib/lib/xcode4/libTestLib_d.a'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

From error above you can see that linker keeps searching for libTestLib_d.a instead of libTestLib.a.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"?

Comment: @EmreÖnder yes I have

Comment: In Xcode's Report Navigator, you can select your build log and then expand the line that starts with "Link".  It will show you the full link command being executed.  That may tell you where the wrong reference is coming from.  (If not, add it to your question and someone will be able to analyze it.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I already did what you mention above before post this question, but I still have no clue (the full link command is too long to read). I will recheck it tomorrow when I get back to work. Maybe I miss something.
I wanted to add it in my question but this is a closed source project from company where I work. The log contains some critical info that I'm afraid I can't share it to public. :|